# How to set timezone of PHP and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, php, timezone

I need to set them to the same timezone.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL timezone management is documented at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html. As for PHP, it's documented at http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone